# routerLink doesn't work in mat-sidenav

Tags: html, angular-material, routerlink, sidenav, angular-routerlink

I have a mat-sidenav in my project and I want to link a text to another URL, but when I use routerLink it doesn't work but it works out of the side-nav.it even works in the toolbar. what is the problem? here are my codes: 
HTML:

```
    <mat-toolbar>
        <mat-toolbar-row>
          <div>
            <button mat-icon-button class="button" (click)="sidemenu.toggle()">
              <mat-icon class="menu">menu</mat-icon>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
        </mat-toolbar-row>
   </mat-toolbar>
   <mat-sidenav-container>
        <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened #sidemenu>
        </mat-sidenav>
        <mat-sidenav-content>
          <div routerLink="/">home</div>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
       </mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example... https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Where is the `[routerLink]` in your code?

Comment: @k-vincentI edited the post. my router link is in mat-sidenav-content

Comment: @bugs I edited my question and I'm there is no other file related to this part.